# ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList is not Comparable

Tags: java, hashmap, mapping, treemap

I have two arrays in my Hash map and I want to sort the values stored in the averageValueArray according to the time in the timeStampArray. I am using `TreeMap` but I am getting `ClassCastException` which says that ArrayList is not comparable.

This is what I am doing:

```
Map<List<Date>,List<Double>> sortMap = new HashMap<List<Date>,List<Double>>();
            sortMap.put(timeStampArray, averageValueArray);

            for (Map.Entry entry : sortMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey());
                System.out.println(" Value = " +entry.getValue());

            }
            System.out.println("Unsort Map......");
            printMap(sortMap);

            System.out.println("Sorted Map......");
            TreeMap<List<Date>,List<Double>> treeMap = new TreeMap<List<Date>,List<Double>>(sortMap);
            for (Map.Entry entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey());
                System.out.println(" Value = " +entry.getValue());

            }


            printMap(treeMap);
```

And the printMap is:

```
public static void printMap(Map<List<Date>,List<Double>> map) {
for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : "
        + entry.getValue());}}
```

Comment: at what line are you getting exception?

Comment: @SumitDesai `         TreeMap<List<Date>,List<Double>> treeMap = new TreeMap<List<Date>,List<Double>>(sortMap);`

Comment: Sounds like what you need is `TreeMap<Date, Double>`. And iterate through each list to put pair of ts and avg val to map. But it's not clear how they (lists) are related.

Answer (score 5):

As the error message says, `ArrayList` does not implement the `Comparable` interface that is required by `TreeMap` to do the ordering of the elements in the map. You can, however, create the `TreeMap` with the constructor that takes a `Comparator` instead, and implement the comparator according to your ordering rules.

Answer (score 4):

From Java doc of [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

[`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) does not implements `Comparable` so you need to provide `Comparator`

I still can't figure out why are you using `List`. What you need can just be possible using `TreeMap<Date, Double>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a comparator as the key of your tree map doesn't implement the Comparable interface.

There's a TreeMap constructor which accepts a custom Comparator and you can implement that with your custom logic.